# overflow style in menu display

Tags: css, html

In my menu I use `overflow:hidden` and menu width to display my menu and hide text if the screen size becomes smaller. However it hides also the submenu at the same time

By submenu I mean the menu of level > 2 
So if I hover an item in the menu bar, I can get the menu display but if that menu contains some subitems then they won't display at all. But when I delete overflow:hidden in my css that is being applied for `ul/li` elements to create the menu, they show up but the text looks ugly especially if it is longer than the menu width

Comment: can you explain in more details with code or screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using this should work:

```css
ul{
    overflow:visible;
}
ul.li{
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul.li.ul{
    overflow:visible;
}
ul.li.ul.li{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Of course you will have to apply it to your own stylesheet. I am not totaly sure this will work, becouse i cant see your code/stylesheet from here.